# Wordpress pagination headache

Tags: wordpress, loops

I'm using the standard wordpress loop to return posts. The only modification I've made to the default WP post is to re-label post as news within the functions file.

```
function revcon_change_post_label() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;
    $menu[5][0] = 'News';
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'News';
    $submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Add News';
    $submenu['edit.php'][16][0] = 'News Tags';
}
function revcon_change_post_object() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $labels = &$wp_post_types['post']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'News';
    $labels->singular_name = 'News';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add News';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add News';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit News';
    $labels->new_item = 'News';
    $labels->view_item = 'View News';
    $labels->search_items = 'Search News';
    $labels->not_found = 'No News found';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No News found in Trash';
    $labels->all_items = 'All News';
    $labels->menu_name = 'News';
    $labels->name_admin_bar = 'News';
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'revcon_change_post_label' );
add_action( 'init', 'revcon_change_post_object' );
```

With permalinks set to `plain` pagination works just fine. But when I change permalinks to `post name` pagination ceases to function? Either following the pagination links or manually going to /news/page/2/ simply reloads /news/.

If I go to /news/page/72/ pagination begins to work again up to the final page (83) but navigating down to /news/page/71 takes me back to /news/ again.

I've tried: 
• Stripping out parts of the loop incase there was something breaking things. 
• Disabling plugins (I cant disable all as this is a live site).
• Creating a paged loop using wp_Query

Nothing has worked except changing the permalink structure to `plain` so urls are returned as siteurl.com/?p=123.

This is driving me crazy! Can anyone sugest something I've not tried?

```
<?php $loopcounter = 1; if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="col-1-1 mobile-col-1-1 nopad clearfix news-loop">
            <div class="col-4-12 mobile-col-1-1 clearfix">  
            <!-- post thumbnail -->
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) :?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- /post thumbnail -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-8-12 mobile-col-1-1 clearfix">
                <!-- post title -->
                <h2>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h2>
                <!-- /post title -->


                <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_custom_post') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <!-- /article -->
    <?php if ($loopcounter % 5 == 0):?>
        <div class="col-1-1 mobile-col-1-1 nopad clearfix loopcta">
            <?php get_template_part('cta2'); ?>
        </div>  
    <?php endif;?>
<?php $loopcounter++; endwhile; ?>
<?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
<?php else: ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article>
        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'a51_blank' ); ?></h2>
    </article>
    <!-- /article -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you are using  Hemisphere-WPTheme ?

Comment: No, it's a custom theme bult on the "html5 blank" boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to work out the issue but creating a page template with a paged `wp_query` worked under the url /test/ but when implementing this under the url /news/ it broke again. The workaround I've found for the time being has been to create a /company-news/ page and set up a 301 to redirect /news/ to /company-news/.

I know this isn't really a solution as I've not solved whatever the issue with the default loop is, however, it works for now.

Code:

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$news_arg = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page'=> 10, 'paged' => $paged );
$news_query = new WP_Query($news_arg);

global $wp_query;
$tmp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $news_query;


$loopcounter = 1; if ($news_query->have_posts()): while ($news_query->have_posts()) : $news_query->the_post(); ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <div class="col-1-1 mobile-col-1-1 nopad clearfix news-loop">
            <div class="col-4-12 mobile-col-1-1 clearfix">  
            <!-- post thumbnail -->
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- /post thumbnail -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-8-12 mobile-col-1-1 clearfix">
                <!-- post title -->
                <h2>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h2>
                <!-- /post title -->


                <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_custom_post'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <!-- /article -->
    <?php if ($loopcounter % 5 == 0):?>
        <div class="col-1-1 mobile-col-1-1 nopad clearfix loopcta">
            <?php get_template_part('cta2'); ?>
        </div>  
    <?php endif;?>
<?php $loopcounter++; endwhile; ?>
<style>.navigation.pagination h2{display:none;}</style>
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size'  => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Previous', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'textdomain' ),
) );?>

<?php else: ?>

    <!-- article -->
    <article>
        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'a51_blank' ); ?></h2>
    </article>
    <!-- /article -->
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); endif; 
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $tmp_query;?>
```